# MiniProfiler ASP.NET MVC5 not able to get results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I am trying to use MiniProfiler for the ASP.NET MVC application. I installed the following NuGet packages. I configured the MiniProfiler in both Global.ascx and Also the script in my _Layout. But I am getting post script error for getting results. The loads without issue. But I don't get the results and no Icon on browser because there is no result to display due to POST error.

1- MiniProfiler.MVC5
2- MiniProfiler.EF6

Error:
[image]

Web.Config:

[image]

Global.ascx - application start:

[image]

[image]

Load script tag:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation, you'll accumulate MiniProfilers that never end, likely resulting in a memory leak (I'm noting this in case you're investigating those symptoms). It's a quick fix though!

If you check out the MiniProfiler MVC5 sample project here: [Samples.Mvc5/Global.asax](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/main/samples/Samples.Mvc5/Global.asax.cs#L70-L73), the important difference is where the profiler is stopped. Ultimately, you want the `Application_EndRequest` (magically named) method to stop a per-request profiler, rather than the current `Application_End` which will only shut down the current profiler (...which is likely `null`) when the application finally ends overall.